# How to convert apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector to arrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, type-conversion, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to convert `apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` to `ArrayList` in Java.

The source code is like this:

```
Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
ArrayList<String> vectorList = new ArrayList<String>(vector);
```

the error is:

```
Cannot resolve constructor
'ArrayList(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector)'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a `Vector` to an `ArrayList<String>` directly. `Vector` provides a `toArray()` method ([documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/Vector.html#toArray--)) which returns an array of type `double`, using which you can convert it into an `ArrayList<String>` as below:

```
        Vector vector = (Vector) row.get(1);
        double[] vectorArray = vector.toArray();
        ArrayList<String> vectorList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double vectorElement: vectorArray) {
            vectorList.add(String.valueOf(vectorElement));
        }
```